# Laravel not displaying images

Tags: laravel-4

I'm having troubles to display the images I upload in the database. I think is beacuse i'm not saving the image correctly?

in my controller :

```
if ( Input::hasFile('thumbnail') ) {

            $file               = Input::file('thumbnail'); // Get the image input
            $destinationPath    = 'uploads/images/thumbnails'; // The destination were you store the image.
            $filename           =  time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName() ; // Original file name that the end user used for it.
            $file               = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename); // Now we move the file to its new home.
            $input['thumbnail'] = $file->getRealPath();
        }

        $model = Model::create($input);
```

and I try this 2 things to display, none of this works:

```
<img src='{{ asset($model->thumbnail) }}'>
                    <!-- {{ HTML::image( $model->thumbnail, 'foto') }} -->
```

this is the path on the database:
/home/vagrant/code/myApp/public/uploads/images/thumbnails/1405976987_C360_2014-05-31-22-09-28-012.jpg

Comment: Check your database table and make sure that the path to your thumbnail is actually stored in database (which most likely isn't). `$destinationPath` should really use one of Laravel path helper (e.g. `base_path()` to give you fully qualified path. Your code seems to be missing chunks of other section too.

Comment: I edit my question to show the path to the database.

Comment: Ok, that is the path to your file, but not the accessible URL to the image. You'll probably better off storing the relative path and convert that to url. e.g. your relative path should be `uploads/images/thumbnails/1405976987_C360_2014-05-31-22-09-28-012.jpg`, save that in your model as `$input['thumbnail_url']`, and call `asset($model->thumbnail_url)` instead.